# HTML and other code integration

Tags: html, web, integration

I am new to coding, and I've picked up HTML and CSS and I'm loving it so far. However I do have a question regarding website creation.

When creating a website -- For example, I want to have a button on my website with a custom color that takes you to a log in page? Is there a way to integrate multiple code languages into one masterpiece? Because I've heard you'd need to know another language like PHP for account logins and scripting all of that.

So my design language is using HTML + CSS
I want to add additional applications that use other more powerful coding languages i.e. Java / C / C++ / PHP

Answer (score 0):

Great question, this isn't obvious when you're starting out. Anything like C, C++, Python, Java, etc. will need to run on servers that interact (or host) your website. PHP and Javascript will actually be delivered with your HTML and CSS to users. This is fairly over-simplified, but if you're starting out I'd suggest learning PHP or Javascript. I'm partial to JS, seems to be getting more popular every day, but certainly PHP is valuable to learn as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just trying to wrap my brain around the whole general idea of coding and how powerful it can be. Starting from the very most basic steps feels like I'm an old man in a kindergarten class, but I know if I build a strong foundation from the start things will come easier.

Comment: @TylerKinsey absolutely. Everyone on SE can probably remember feeling that way. I'd try and find an entry level JS tutorial/project that will cover how it interacts with your site.